How to retrieve Instagram user information using API (ID, follower count, media count, etc.)?
I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve and store Instagram user information through an API. Specifically, I need the following data:
ID
Username
Follower count
Following count
Profile picture
Media count
Biography
Whether the account is verified
Whether the account is private
The problem I am facing is that Instagram Basic Display API only provides my own data. It does not allow me to get detailed other user informations.

Your problem seems to be with the Instagram API, not with programming ... Is there some kind of support from IG ?

For the most part, getting other people's information, requires them to give consent to that first. The Basic Display API however has been deprecated, and there currently is no replacement. So you can only work with professional IG accounts (business/creator) via the official APIs.

You can get most of the data you're after using the graph.instagram.com/{user_id} API. You can see the full list of supported properties (fields) in the official docs (ignore the incorrect "graph.facebook.com" domain in their sample code).
The only constraint for this is that you can only fetch data for users who have authorized your app. With the deprecation of Instagram Basic Display API, you are limited only to Create/Business accounts, using the new Instagram Business API (Instagram API with Instagram Login). You will need to create a Business app and request the instagram_business_basic_permissions from your users.
